# Python recursion to split string by sliding window

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently, I face an interesting coding task that involves splitting a string multiple permutations with a given K-limit size.

For example:

```
s = "iamfoobar"
k = 4  # the max number of the items on a list after the split
```

The `s` can split into the following combinations

```
[
    ["i", "a", "m", "foobar"],
    ["ia", "m", "f", "oobar"],
    ["iam", "f", "o", "obar"]
# etc
]
```

I tried to figure out how to do that with a quick recursively function, but I cannot get it to work.

I have try this out, but didn't seem to work

```
def sliding(s, k):
    if len(s) < k:
        return []
    else:
        for i in range(0, k):
            return [s[i:i+1]] + sliding(s[i+1:len(s) - i], k)

print(sliding("iamfoobar", 4))
```

And only got this

```
['i', 'a', 'm', 'f', 'o', 'o']
```

Comment: Iterate over the number of characters you want to take for the next (leftmost) slice and calculate recursively the options for the remaining characters and remaining cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first main problem is that although you use a loop, you immediately return a single list. So no matter how much you fix everything around, your output will never match what you expect as it will be.... a single list.

Second, on the recursive call you start with `s[i:i+1]` but according to your example you want all prefixes, so something like `s[:i]` is more suitable.

Additionaly, in the recursive call you never reduce `k` which is the natural recursive step.

Lastly, your stop condition seems wrong also. As above, if the natural step is reducing `k`, the natural stop would be `if k == 1` then `return [[s]]`. This is because the only way to split the string to 1 part is the string itself...

---

The important thing is to keep in mind your final output format and think how that can work in your step. In this case you want to return a list of all possible permutations as lists. So in case of `k == 1`, you simply return a list of a single list of the string.

Now as the step, you want to take a different prefix each time, and add to it all permutations from the call of the rest of the string with `k-1`. All in all the code can be something like this:

```py
def splt(s, k):
    if k == 1:  # base sace - stop condition
        return [[s]]

    res = []
    # loop over all prefixes
    for i in range(1, len(s)-k+2):
        for tmp in splt(s[i:], k-1):
            # add to prefix all permutations of k-1 parts of the rest of s
            res.append([s[:i]] + tmp)
    return res
```

You can test it on some inputs and see how it works.

---

If you are not restricted to recursion, another approach is to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). You can use that to create all combinations of indexes inside the string to split it into `k` parts, and then simply concatenate those parts and put them in a list. A raw version is something like:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def splt(s, k):
    res = []
    for indexes in combinations(range(1, len(s)), k-1):
        indexes = [0] + list(indexes) + [len(s)] # add the edges to k-1 indexes to create k parts
        res.append([s[start:end] for start, end in zip(indexes[:-1], indexes[1:])]) # concatenate the k parts

    return res
```

Comment: Wow, never learn about `itertools.combinations` and will definitely check it out. 

Thanks

Comment: You could simplify the inner part of the combinations version to just be `res.append([s[start:end] for start, end in zip((0,) + indexes, indexes + (len(s),))])`

Comment: @Sylvaus Indeed! thanks for the input. I really banged my head on finding a proper way to write this so decided it would be most clear splitting the list creation

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your implementation is that your loop does not do what is supposed to do as it returns the first result instead of appending the results.

Here's an example of an implementation:

```py
def sliding(s, k):
    # If there is not enough values of k is below 0
    # there is no combination possible
    if len(s) < k or k < 1:
        return []

    # If k is one, we return a list containing all the combinations,
    # which is a single list containing the string
    if k == 1:
        return [[s]]

    results = []
    # Iterate through all the possible values for the first value
    for i in range(1, len(s) - k + 2):
        first_value = s[:i]
        # Append the result of the sub call to the first values
        for sub_result in sliding(s[i:], k - 1):
            results.append([first_value] + sub_result)

    return results

print(sliding("iamfoobar", 4))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, so double for-loop with a recursive call, that's more complicated than I thought. Thanks! Will test it out!